# Windows cannot be installed on this disk. The selected disk has an MBR partition table. On EFI systems , Windows can only be installed to GPT disks

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I want to format c drive and reinstall windows 8.

previously I've installed windows 8 and ubuntu together in same C drive in separate partitions.previously I've configured ***ubuntu grub*** to select which OS to boot .

So I deleted previous ubuntu partition and windows partition while windows 8 installation (using windows 8 DVD)

Then I try to select following a partition (***Drive 0 Unallocated Space*** 130 GB)to continue the windows 8 installation

[image]

but then I cannot continue it and once I try to **drive options(advanced)** and then **new**

I'm getting error like below

> Windows cannot be installed on this disk. The selected disk has an MBR partition table. On EFI systems, Windows can only be installed to GPT disks
>   [image]

then I Google about this error and I found most of [solutions](http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/i-cant-install-windows-8) like below

> Start Command Prompt
>
> Type In:
>
> DISKPART
>
> LIST DISK and identify your disk number (from 0 to n disks)
>
> SELECT DISK  where  is the disk number
>
> CLEAN ALL (Will Take Some Time)
>
> CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY ALIGN=1024
>
> FORMAT FS=NTFS (Will Take Some Time)
>
> ASSIGN LETTER=M
>
> ACTIVE
>
> EXIT
>
> EXIT
>
> [ Immediately Terminate Install Process Completely ]
>
> And
>
> Reboot using Installation DVD.

If you look at my partitions list(1st image) it has only 1 drive(which Drive 0) and 3 partitions.

when I follow above solutions I'm getting disk list like below

[image]

If I clean disk 0 it will clear all my data including other two partitions , how I can continue installation without losing data in other partitions

simply this is how to

> **Convert MBR to GPT without loosing Data and without OS**

[p.s : now I don't have any OS since I deleted all my os partitions]

Comment: @grawity in your solution will there be any data loss ?

Comment: @grawity here the results I got once I follow solution  3rd step Run `lsblk`

http://oi57.tinypic.com/npnzag.jpg shall I continue , will it loose my data

Comment: The conversion with gdisk only creates a new partition table; it does not destroy data. (You can write down the "start" & "end" addresses from fdisk/gdisk in case of accidents.)

Comment: @grawity thanks lot , you're correct , safely done that